# TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined when comparing objects in an array in React

Tags: reactjs, date, for-loop

I'm slightly new and I'm trying to display a single date for an upcoming trade shows.  I have an array of objects for each show, and am trying to iterate through said array to compare the dates to decipher which date to display.

Example: if there's a show on August 20th, August 30th and October 4th, I'd like to show the upcoming show on the 30th until that day is done, then display October 4th til that show, etc...

Attempt one:

```
    const correctDate = this.props.myEvents.map((myEvent, i) => {
            // debugger
            if (myEvent.eventDate == this.state.todaysDate) { console.log("I work")
                return (
                <div>
                    <h3>{myEvent.eventDate}</h3>
                    <h3>{myEvent.eventStart} - {myEvent.eventEnd}</h3>
                    <h2>{myEvent.eventName}</h2>
                </div> )
            } else if (this.state.todaysDate > myEvent.eventDate && myEvent.eventDate < this.props.myEvents[i + 1].eventDate) { console.log("I work")
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h3>{myEvent.eventDate}</h3>
                        <h3>{myEvent.eventStart} - {myEvent.eventEnd}</h3>
                        <h2>{myEvent.eventName}</h2>
                    </div> )
            } else {
                console.log("idk what's happening but i ran")
            }
        })

    return(
        <div>
            {correctDate}
        </div>
    )
```

This returns the following error :
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventDate' of undefined`
which I though was due to `this.props.myEvents[i + 1].eventDate`

Attempt two:

```
  const correctDate = [] 

  for (let i = 0; i < this.props.myEvents.length; i++) {
         for(let k = 0; k < this.props.myEvents.length; i++) {
             if (this.props.myEvents[i].eventDate == this.state.todaysDate) {
                 correctDate.push(
                     <div>
                         <h3>{this.props.myEvents[i].eventDate}</h3>
                         <h3>{this.props.myEvents[i].eventStart} - {this.props.myEvent[i].eventEnd}</h3>
                         <h2>{this.props.myEvents[i].eventName}</h2>
                     </div>)
             } else if (this.state.todaysDate > this.props.myEvents[i].eventDate && this.props.myEvents[i].eventDate < this.props.myEvents[k].eventDate) {
                 correctDate.push(
                     <div>
                         <h3>{this.props.myEvents[i].eventDate}</h3>
                         <h3>{this.props.myEvents[i].eventStart} - {this.props.myEvent[i].eventEnd}</h3>
                         <h2>{this.props.myEvents[i].eventName}</h2>
                     </div>
                 )
             } else {
                 console.log("I didn't work at all")
             }
         }
     }
```

This gives me the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Not quite.  I can get the comparison fine, it's the render that's causing my troubles. I should probably rephrase my title and be more specific.

Comment: Please also edit the code to include example data, what the results are, and what you want the results to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you just want to render items that take place today or in the future? Can you just sort `myEvents` by date and then filter to remove dates in the past? Anytime I deal with dates I use a utility library, so [moment](https://momentjs.com/) is pretty helpful for stuff like this

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";

const Events = () => {
  const myEvents = [
    {
      eventDate: new Date("07/01/2020"),
      title: "July Jam"
    },
    {
      eventDate: new Date("09/01/2020"),
      title: "September to Remember"
    },
    {
      eventDate: new Date("06/01/2020"),
      title: "June Gloom"
    },
    {
      eventDate: new Date("08/26/2020"),
      title: "August Ice Cream Day 1"
    },
    {
      eventDate: new Date("08/27/2020"),
      title: "August Ice Cream Day 2"
    }
  ];

  let sorted = myEvents
    .sort((a, b) => (a.eventDate > b.eventDate ? 1 : -1))
    .filter((event) =>
      moment(event.eventDate).isSameOrAfter(new Date().toLocaleDateString())
    );

  return (
    <ul>
      {sorted.map(({ eventDate, title }) => (
        <li key={title}>
          {eventDate.toLocaleDateString()} - {title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Events;
```

Now `sorted` will be all the events from today on. So you can just loop through those and render a `<ul />` that looks like this

```
<ul>
  <li>8/26/2020 - August Ice Cream Day 1</li>
  <li>8/27/2020 - August Ice Cream Day 2</li>
  <li>9/1/2020 - September to Remember</li>
</ul>
```

**Update from Comments**
If you just want to show the next event you can just grab the first item in the array. Something like this works.

```
let [nextEvent, ...rest] = myEvents
    .sort((a, b) => (a.eventDate > b.eventDate ? 1 : -1))
    .filter((event) =>
      moment(event.eventDate).isSameOrAfter(new Date().toLocaleDateString())
    );

  return (
    Boolean(nextEvent) && (
      <div>
        Next Event: {nextEvent.title} on{" "}
        {nextEvent.eventDate.toLocaleDateString()}
      </div>
    )
  );
```

Comment: That definitely gets me around the TypeError problem, but I'm looking to display just a single date object for the next upcoming event; i.e., displaying the title for 8/26/2020 today, 8/27/2020 tomorrow, and 9/01/2020 until end of day 9/01/2002, etc... if that makes sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "display a single date object." I updated my answer to show the rendered HTML - which I think is the same thing you describe in your comment.

Comment: Sorry - relatively new to programming so still trying to get better at explaining what I'm trying to do... Instead of returning an ul with all the elements in the array, I just want one single element from the array for the upcoming event.

Comment: That did the trick.  Appreciate your help and patience!